# Remove all lines from a file that contain a non-ascii character

Tags: perl, ascii

I have a file with thousands of lines in it. I would like to search each line for a non-ascii character, and if found, delete that entire line.

I found this bit of code in perl:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print unless(/[^[:ascii:]]/)' file
```

But I get this error when I run it with my file:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

Does anyone have any code for an actual perl script instead of a one liner like the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a shell error, most likely because you're on a windows machine.

Use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
perl -i.bak -ne "print unless(/[^[:ascii:]]/)" file
```

Comment: Yes that would do it. This removes the entire line too correct?

Comment: Yes, this will only keep lines that do not contain a non-ascii character.